# div with display: flex is not centering child div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div with a `display: flex`, and I would like to display the output in a row center. For some reason it is displaying left. I want the `imgBoxBot` to be centered inside the `imgBot` `div`. But `text-align: center` is only centering the text inside the `imgBoxBot`, how do I center the actual `div`?

```css
#imgBot {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
}

#imgBoxBot {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgBot">
  <div id="imgBoxBot">
    test
  </div>
  <div id="imgBoxBot">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use the same id on the same page. change #imgBoxBot to a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `justify-content: center`. You can find more information [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#imgBot {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.imgBoxBot {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgBot">
  <div class="imgBoxBot">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="imgBoxBot">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```